# How to use the Concrete5 "Page Rating" Add-On

Tags: concrete5, rating-system

I have a page that shows search results containing pages that matched the search criteria. All of the pages returned are the same type of page (e.g., a person's profile). I want to add a star rating system to it so users can rate the profile.

I've tried adding a custom page attribute and updating it using the output rating helper but that didn't work. It looked like it worked but when I refreshed the page it just went back to whatever the rating was set to originally.

So, I added the "Page Ratings" add-on (https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/page-ratings/) and installed it. There are supposed to be 2 blocks associalted with it. I'm assuming the list block is the one I need in my case. However, when I go to the page and try to add one of those blocks to my area I don't see them listed. Does anyone know how to use this add-on? There is barely any documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize this is a "pay for" application?  As such, most of the Developers that do charge for their add-ons are very responsive.  Not to push you away from here, but if you have a problem with the installation, payment, etc.  Really should be addressed by the Developer.

Comment: I contacted them but didn't hear back so that's why I'm on here.